# ruby on rails button_to not activating the delete method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi im following the agile web development ebook and i cant seem to activate the logout action

here are the revelant parts (TAB key not working could not format to code)

`rake routes`

`logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                  sessions#destroy`

from the route file

```
controller :sessions do
    get 'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
    delete 'logout' => :destroy
  end
```

my controller

```
def destroy
session[:user_id] = user.id
redirect_to store_url , notice: "Logged out"
end
```

and my view (relevant part)
`<%= button_to 'Logout', logout_path, method: :delete %>`

the error message is 
No route matches [GET] "/logout"

i know it should use delete method but nothing i do seems to help

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a `match` in your routes. Sorry that I don't have the book with me to refer to.

Put this above your `controller :sessions ...`

```
match 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
```

If you didn't put the above line, your logout path should be `sessions_logout_path`, not `logout_path`.

Reference:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

Comment: Sounds like he already has the path alright but the form is being sent over `GET` instead of `POST`+`DELETE`.

Comment: both suggestions work but the problem was in my controller method ,i accidently made it equal to user.id whereas it should be nil

Answer (score 0):

`match '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :via => :delete`

or

```
controller :sessions do
  member do
     delete :destroy, :as => :logout
  end
end
```

Comment: the problem was in my controller instead of setting it to nil i wrote user.id and there is no user variable there.